# Working with a ListBox from an SQL database

Tags: c#

I'm new to CS.  I have a ListBox control that I populate from an SQL table called Category.  I have a class called Category to match the fields from the DB.  I want all my fields available to edit and save.  The ListBox has a single field, CategoryDesc.  When I select an item in the ListBox I want two textboxes and a check box to update with the CategoryID (string), CategoryDesc (string), and IsActive (bool).  I have it working but it seems cumbersome and like I'm taking a lot of steps.  I want to learn efficient coding so I'm submitting the following for suggestions on how to clean it up and make it more efficient.  Any positive comments will be greatly appreciated.

```
id ListControl()
    {
        this.LstCategory.SelectedIndexChanged -= new System.EventHandler(this.LstCategory_SelectedIndexChanged);
        DataTable categoryDt = new DataTable();
        categoryDt = GetDataTable("GetListCategory");
        for (int i = 0; i < categoryDt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            category.Add(new Category()
            {
                CategoryID = (int)(categoryDt.Rows[i]["CategoryId"]),
                CategoryDesc = (string)(categoryDt.Rows[i]["CategoryDesc"]),
                ShortCode = (string)(categoryDt.Rows[i]["ShortCode"]),
                IsActive = (bool)(categoryDt.Rows[i]["IsActive"]),
                CanDelete = (bool)(categoryDt.Rows[i]["CanDelete"])
            });
            LstCategory.Items.Add((string)(categoryDt.Rows[i]["CategoryDesc"]));
        }

        this.LstCategory.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.LstCategory_SelectedIndexChanged);
    }

    private void LstCategory_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (LstCategory.SelectedIndex >= 0)
        {
            string desc = LstCategory.SelectedItem.ToString();
            foreach (var c in category)
            {
                if (c.CategoryDesc == desc)
                {
                    TxtDescription.Text = c.CategoryDesc;
                    TxtShortCode.Text = c.ShortCode;
                    ChkIsActive.Checked = c.IsActive;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            TxtDescription.Text = string.Empty;
            TxtShortCode.Text = string.Empty;
            ChkIsActive.Checked = false;
        }
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Learn to use Linq

This

```
    categoryDt = GetDataTable("GetListCategory");
    for (int i = 0; i < categoryDt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        category.Add(new Category()
        {
            CategoryID = (int)(categoryDt.Rows[i]["CategoryId"]),
            CategoryDesc = (string)(categoryDt.Rows[i]["CategoryDesc"]),
            ShortCode = (string)(categoryDt.Rows[i]["ShortCode"]),
            IsActive = (bool)(categoryDt.Rows[i]["IsActive"]),
            CanDelete = (bool)(categoryDt.Rows[i]["CanDelete"])
        });
        LstCategory.Items.Add((string)(categoryDt.Rows[i]["CategoryDesc"]));
    }
```

can be replaced by

```
   category = categoryDt.Select(cd => new Category{
            CategoryID = (int)(cd["CategoryId"]),
            CategoryDesc = (string)(cd[i]["CategoryDesc"]),
            ShortCode = (string)(cd["ShortCode"]),
            IsActive = (bool)(cd[i]["IsActive"]),
            CanDelete = (bool)(cd[i]["CanDelete"])}).ToList();
   LstCategory.Items.AddRange(category.Select(c=>c.Desc));
```

and

```
       string desc = LstCategory.SelectedItem.ToString();
        foreach (var c in category)
        {
            if (c.CategoryDesc == desc)
            {
                TxtDescription.Text = c.CategoryDesc;
                TxtShortCode.Text = c.ShortCode;
                ChkIsActive.Checked = c.IsActive;
            }
        }
```

can be replaced by

```
        var c = category.FirstOrDefault(c=>c ==desc);
        TxtDescription.Text = c.CategoryDesc;
        TxtShortCode.Text = c.ShortCode;
        ChkIsActive.Checked = c.IsActive;
```

There might be a few typos here and there becuase I dont have yur data structures to try it out on.

But LINQ is incredibly useful for performing operations on collections.

- 'select' is used to transform 'project' (its not a filter)
- 'where' is used to filter
- 'FindFirstOrDefault' will retunr the first match (or null)
- 'Count' counts
- 'ToList' converts to list

The nice thing is you can chain then together

```
mylist.Where(...).Select(..) etc
```

Comment: A better option would be to add the `Category` objects directly and use `DisplayMember` to choose what to display

Comment: Thanks.  I write a lot of SQL code so for the most part I understand LINQ, just not when to use it.  Thanks again for the insight.  You have been very helpful.

Comment: Oops! Now I get the nebulous error message. "CS1660: cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type" on the category = categorryDt... expression.

Comment: I have using System.Data;   using System.Linq;   I tried to add using System.Data.Entity; but that created an error.